# What happens to the memory allocated on my local variable

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

Below is my sample method:

```
private async Task<Model[]> GetModels()
{
   var toProcess = new List<Model>();
   toProcess.Add(new Model());
   return toProcess.ToArray();
}
```

What will happen to the toProcess object memory? will it get reclaimed by GC as toProcess.ToArray() will make of copy of elements?

I do not find how to verify this memory is reclaimed by GC using diagnostics tool in VS2022. I verified that object allocation tool is always showing this model[] allocation is happening not sure it is getting disposed/reclaimed.

Comment: Since `toProcess` is the only variable able to reach that `List<Model>` instance, when the function returns the object becomes unreachable.  The GC will clean up unreachable objects *eventually* but not immediately.